# Почему возвращаемый интерфейс из функции не работает как нужно?

Tags: typescript

Обожаю статическую типизацию, но ненавижу `TypeScript`.
В общем, сами посмотрите [пример глюка](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgM4HsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMhcpKmAIwD8AXGmFKAOYA05l1YATExZsQXUgF9SpMAE8ADigzYAKvJQBeZAAotASmTqAfGiy58sRBH0AfE9jyQLSKQnQgadiADEAriAQG2nJwUHCYzEoQqgr6RsgA5AAW0CgA7ijs6PEA3FIA9HnIAKJQUOhQzHwAzMgAJugQqCDxYMgQAB7ANKSRvv5axFSNdMzx8ZxDNPyj45NgVTPI4rq5pAXIAHIA8srFpeU9pn0IOrHGWjwUg3y0MxN80wmz1YuSuitAA)

```
interface someInterface {
    test1?: string,
    test2?: string,
}

type someType = (() => someInterface) | someInterface

const someFunc = (param: someType) => 'here we go';

// Error: test3 doesn't exist
someFunc({ test1: '', test2: '', test3: '' });

// NOT Error
someFunc(() => (
    { test1: '', test2: '', test3: '' }
));
```

В функцию `someFunc` можно передавать интерфейс или функцию, которая возвращает интерфейс.
Когда мы передаём в качестве аргумента просто интерфейс, то все работает как нужно, но когда функцию, то происходит какой-то глюк. То-есть, можно добавлять любые свойства и `TypeScript` не будет ругаться.

Почему это происходит?

Comment: во втором случае тип возвращаемого значения функции не `someInterface`, а выводится из типа возвращаемого объекта. При этом этот объект можно присвоить типу someInterface, поэтому ошибки нет. Кроме того, проверка полного соответствия полей работает только с литералами объектов.

Comment: В других случаях уже не проверяется ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgM4HsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMhcpKmAIwD8AXGmFKAOYA05l1YATExZsQXUgF9SpAG5woyAEbIAvCSoQatZgHJtndTX469BsAGZjycQG4Zc5HAUJmGbHkixEKVQutA)). Если нужна проверка в данном случае, можно добавить тип возвращаемого значения у функции `someFunc(():someInterface => (
    { test1: '', test2: '', test3: '' }
));`

Comment: @Grundy Почему `TypeScript` автоматически это не определил? Ведь ранее тип был задан. С явным указанием возвращемого типа будет много будблей по коду. Автоматизировать никак нельзя?

Comment: @Grundy а на самом деле тип возвращаемого значения функции `someInterface`, просто помиму указанных в интерфейсе функций ещё можно добавлять любые другие. Странное поведение!

Comment: _а на самом деле тип возвращаемого значения функции someInterface_ - конечно нет. Ты можешь вынести эту функцию в переменную и посмотреть подсказку - тип будет другим.

Answer (score 3):

При работе с литералами объекта, typescript [строго проверяет соответствие](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) интерфейсу, чтобы исключить разные опечатки.

Поэтому в первом случае происходит ошибка: **литерал**

```
{ test1: '', test2: '', test3: '' }
```

содержит лишнее поле, которого нет в интерфейсе.

---

Что происходит во втором случае: в качестве параметра передается **функция**

```
() => (
    { test1: '', test2: '', test3: '' }
)
```

Так как прямо не указан тип возвращаемого значения, он выводится автоматически. В данном случае тип возвращаемого значения будет

```
{
    test1: string;
    test2: string;
    test3: string;
}
```

Далее идет проверка, можно ли объект данного типа присвоить переменной с типом `someInterface` - и это действительно возможно, так как в типе присутствуют все обязательные поля. Поэтому никакой ошибки в этом случае быть и не должно.

Answer (score 1):

Если написать так, то проверит

```
interface someInterface {
    test1?: string,
    test2?: string,
}

type someType = (() => someInterface) | someInterface

const someFunc = (param: someType) => 'here we go';

// Error: test3 doesn't exist
someFunc({ test1: '', test2: '', test3: '' });

// NOT Error
someFunc(():someInterface => ({ test1: '', test2: '', test3: '' }));
```

Comment: что именно поменялось? :) Все ли изменения необходимы? :)

Comment: Ну return можно было не писать, убрал. )))

Comment: а тип someType зачем менять?

Comment: Точно. Ошибся! Спасибо, что поправили)))

Comment: Странность в том, что просто интерфейс определяется, а для функции нужно явно указывать интерфейс (дублировать). Жестоко!

Comment: Согласен с Вами